# Socket with Python

Tags: python, sockets

I read some of the Sockets documentation and watched some videos on the subject, I tried to make the sockets connection. First, I tried it with my internal IP, ran it on different endpoints and everything worked. I tried it with my external IP and it failed, I tried to run the same application on different devices, I ran server.py on my PC, and I ran client.py on my cell phone. No error message appeared, but the connection did not start.

Server code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket() 
print("Socket successfully created")

port = 12345
s.bind(('Meu IP', port))
print("socket binded to %s" %(port))

s.listen(5)
print ("socket is listening")

while True:

     c, addr = s.accept()
     print('Got connection from', addr )
     c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())

     c.close()
```

Client code:

```
# Import socket module
import socket

s = socket.socket()

port = 12345

s.connect(('IP', port))

print (s.recv(1024).decode())
s.close()
```

I think the problem is the IP, I think I should put the valid external IP instead of the internal IP, but I don't know how to do that, because when I try this, an error appears. I just need to know how to create a socket between two machines on different networks. I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time. If any of you can help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: You will need IP address which is globally accessible. Your local Internet Service Provider will not allow you to do this, so you will have to host on cloud platforms where they will allow you to do what you are thinking of, and will provide you IP address accessible from anywhere.